# Way to create a new database in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, hosting

I'm trying to setup a forum app in my wordpress website and it needs a database.

I've a wordpress hosting plan that is provided by Godaddy. It hasn't got a cPanel to create MySQL database. I'm able to reach phpMyAdmin but also there is no option to create a new database. I can run SQL query/queries on database an existing database but I'm not sure how can this help me as I don't know anything about sql. Also there is an option to import database but I have no idea about what should I do.

Sorry if I couldn't explain it well. I have a little idea about the things that I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Basic hosting plan only provide a single DB. So you can't create another one...

Check to upgrade your hosting ;)

---

Depending of the forum you choose (I'm thinking of SMF by example) you can use the same DB than your WP and **set a prefix for the forum's tables** (`smf_*` or `forum_`).

The next thing to look is if you're allowed to host something else than a WP (probably not) and if you can create sub domain like `forum.mydomain.com` instead of the `mydomain.com/forum/`.

If you're familiar with hosting, you can take a small shared one (it may even be cheaper than your actual plan) and host both WP and the forum. But you'll had to go go for mid-range if you want multiple DB management (usually provided under "reseller plan")

Comment: "Check to upgrade your hosting ;)" Preferably by ditching GoDaddy entirely.

Comment: @ceejayoz ditching "packed-hosting" more than anything else. I've never tried GoDaddy, so I can't tell how bad is it.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with hosting and database related things. (Trying to learn by doing and mostly failing as you can see by the example above. :,) ) So if using the same database with WP is possible, can anybody teach me how to do it? I'm trying to use Vanilla forums( Open-source vanillaforums.org ) It's asking me database host, name, user, and password to proceed. So what now? Thanks.

Comment: @EgeEmsun first : backup of the WP tables (if you overwrite one, you'll be glad to have a backup). Next, I don't know if godaddy give you your `host, db_name, user, password` credentials, it's the same as the WP if you can find them